# Append elements on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, round-slider

I'm using [roundSlider](https://github.com/soundar24/roundSlider) for radial slider. Which gives me value on slide. 
on slide I'm appeding `span` elements.

So what I want exactly is `span` should as per plates number. If there are 22 plates so `span` should be only 22 and if plates are 10 then `span` should also be 10 or vice-versa.

**[Find Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a6devr3b/1/)**

Currently, It's just appending in 1 length. I want it to append (add and remove) as per `var tp` value.

```
var tp = $('.rs-tooltip').text() / 1000;
$('#plates span').text(tp);
$('.mbox').append('<span></span>')
```

Comment: [See the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6devr3b/2/) are you like this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo Fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/a6devr3b/2/)

add with for loop event .The for loop will append the `span` depend on span value. Initially remove inner content of `.mbox` .Then its will re added with a help of for loop

```
function traceEvent(e) {
        var tp = $('.rs-tooltip').text() / 1000;
        console.log(tp);
      $('#plates span').text(tp);
      $('.mbox').html("");//empty
    for(var i=0; i<tp; i++){
        $('.mbox').append('<span id="'+[i]+'"></span>')//add
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

See updated here: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/a6devr3b/3/

I did a small change on your `traceEvent` method to empty the plates first.

```
function traceEvent(e) {
    var tp = $('.rs-tooltip').text() / 1000;
    console.log(tp);
    $('#plates span').text(tp);
    $('.mbox').html('');
    for (i = 0; i < tp; i++ )
    $('.mbox').append('<span/>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check below code
1. remove all span
2. add span base on tp value

```
 function traceEvent(e) {
  var tp = $('.rs-tooltip').text() / 1000;
  $('#plates span').text(tp);
  $('.mbox').html("");
  for(var i=0; i<tp; i++){
     $('.mbox').append('<span></span>');
  }
 }
```